# Can't get ADC chip to work

Tags: fpga, adc, potentiometer

I am connecting a 10k potentiometer to an ADC chip ([LTC1273BCN](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/127356fa.pdf)) that has a 12-bit parallel output, like in the diagram at the end of the post. The 12-bits will be connected to an FPGA input bus after I can get it to work correctly. The ADC chip circuit is powered off a stable 5V from a lab benchtop power supply.

I have tied the CS and RD inputs low as I thought this will continuously run the conversion but maybe this is my problem, I am unsure.

When I measure the voltage of the 12 output pins, only pin 14 (D2) seems to be high, the rest are 0V. The Ain voltage is perfect between 0 and 4.99V from the potentiometer, and I have tied the HBEN input to 5V as I want to use all 12-bits in one conversion.

Any advice as to how to use this chip correctly? Will I have to pulse the CS and RD inputs low to get the chip to behave as I would like? I don't really want to use signals from the FPGA to control the analog to digital conversion.

***EDIT***

Below is my reasoning behind the pin connections:

Pin 1 : 0V to 5V from potentiometer, to be converted to 0 to 4095 by ADC chip.

Pin 2 : I haven't used this pin but have attached capacitors to pin 3 according to datasheet.

Pin 3 : Tied to analog ground which is the same ground as chip supply.

Pins 4 to 11 : D11 to D4 output bits are left unconnected.

Pin 12 : Tied to ground of power supply.

Pins 13 to 16 : D3 to D0 output bits are left unconnected.

Pins 17 and 18 : Left unconnected as in datasheet.

Pin 19 : Tied to 5V to use the full 12 bits in one conversion instead of splitting into 2 conversions in one byte.

Pin 20 : Tied to ground for continuous conversion ( if this is possible).

Pin 21 : Tied to ground to allow for continuous conversion ( if this is possible).

Pin 22 : Left unconnected as I am not using it.

Pin 23 : NC

Pin 24 : +5V from power supply to power up ADC chip.

Thanks everyone.

[image: ADC Circuit diagram image]

Comment: Please provide a data sheet link and explain what it is in the DS that prompted you to choose the above circuit to trial.

Comment: @Andyaka Have just added datasheet and will edit the question now.

Comment: From what I can see in the datasheet, you can't continuously pull RD and CS low. There needs to be a delay between conversions and between two read operations (t10 and t11 from the datasheet).

Comment: How are you expecting the FPGA to know when the data is valid so that it can read it reliably?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yeah, I have learned from this post that I have a design flaw. I am going to now use the FPGA to start the conversion by pulling the pin low, and then after the conversion time, set the pin high again and read/store the ADC value into a register. Then repeat this process synchronously after a time delay.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Justme gave the answer, you have to clock it.

> continuous conversion without having to initialise and command the conversion?

That would mean the ADC would change the level of its output pins every time it does a new conversion. Counting uneven propagation delays, skew, etc, if the device that reads these pins reads them at the wrong time, it will get some bits from the previous value, some bits from the new value, and some bits in transition which will be garbage.

That's why synchronous logic uses clock to synchronize things and ensure signals are sampled when they are valid.

If an ADC does continuous conversion, it must have an output with an edge to indicate when the data is valid and can be sampled by the next device. You will need to apply proper clock domain crossing to that in your FPGA. It is simpler to just generate the timing signal from the FPGA, plus you will get a stable sample frequency instead of whatever RC internal oscillator the ADC uses.

Note for 300ksps you don't need a flash ADC, a SAR will do just fine, and it's cheaper.

EDIT:

> Mainly because I have to use opto-couplers between the FPGA and the ADC bits, so I will have to also isolate the CS and RD signals from the FPGA too.

OK, so you want an isolated reading on a potentiometer. I really wonder why, but there are much simpler solutions for that.

- SPI ADC. Pretty cheap, less opto couplers. It will be fast enough.
- Isolated ADC (check mouser/digikey). Should be expensive.
- Cheap micro as the ADC, output the data on a UART, isolate that, and instantiate a UART receiver in your FPGA.
- Or turn the pot signal into PWM, or variable frequency, or pulse density modulation (many ways of doing this, 555, opamps, etc), isolate it with one opto, and read the duty cycle, period, etc with a timer/counter in your FPGA.

Comment: I would like isolated signals between the FPGA and the potentiometer circuit as the FPGA development board is powered through the computer's USB port and the potentiometer circuit is supplied from a 5V power supply. So they need to be isolated.

Comment: It's not dangerous voltage, you could power the pot from the FPGA board instead.

Comment: The only problem with doing that is, there is nowhere on the FPGA board to get 5V. Everything is 3.3V

Comment: You can use 3V3 to power a pot, it doesn't care about voltage...

Comment: @David777 You can disable USB powering and use an external power supply on every development board I've ever seen (and in 25 years in industry I've seen a few!).

Comment: @bobflux But I can't use 3.3V to power up the ADC chip. It requires 5V

Comment: @Graham But I can only use the FPGA development board when it is connected to the PC and Vivado as I don't store the configuration on the FPGA.

Comment: Why cares? Are you married to this ADC chip from the 1990's? You can get a 10 bit I2C ADC that runs on 3V3 for $1. Or you can instantiate a sigma delta ADC core in your FPGA for $0. It's accurate enough to read a pot.

Comment: @David777 I didn't say "don't connect USB", I said "don't use the power supply from the USB". I have a Xilinx FPGA in the product my company has been selling for the last 3 years, and I wrote all the code including initializing the FPGA. So I know that a Xilinx FPGA will sit and wait indefinitely after power-on until it gets an image file. Power everything from USB, or power everything from a separate power supply. You can't ever do a bizarre mixture where some bits of your circuit die randomly if the USB disconnects. That's just bad design. Whoever is supervising you should tell you that.

Comment: @bobflux I have now bought a 3.3V 12 bit ADC chip (AD7476ABRMZ) with serial output instead of parallel 5V output. Does away with all the opto-couplers and 12 bus wires + clock from the FPGA.

Comment: Excellent, much simpler this way!

Answer (score 5):

No it won't work like that, page 15 of the datasheet describes how the chip bus works.

At least some of the control signals need to have transitions, this chip is intended to be sitting on a memory bus so it looks like RAM or ROM chip.

Comment: Ok, I see. My next question is do such ADC chips exist that allow for continuous conversion without having to initialise and command the conversion?

Comment: Most likely such chips exist, I am quite sure of that.

Comment: Ok, I will see what I can find, thanks.

Comment: Maybe my best solution is to use the FPGA to control the ADC conversion or another external circuit like a 555 timer to generate the signals?

Comment: Maybe. Hard to say as you don't mention what are you doing as a whole. I do hope you are not seriously thinking of adding extra hardware, especially a 555 timer, to help interfacing something to an FPGA which already is reconfigurable hardware.

Comment: I am only considering extra hardware as I would prefer not to use FPGA pins to control it. I have a processor on the FPGA and I read from the ADC chip cyclically in the program I have created and stored in RAM. So I would like the ADC chip to continuously convert the potentiometer input and the FPGA can read from it by storing the 12 ADC bits into a register to be handled and scaled in the program.

Comment: Mainly because I have to use opto-couplers between the FPGA and the ADC bits, so I will have to also isolate the CS and RD signals from the FPGA too.

Comment: It does not sound like isolating 12+ pins is a good idea, especially since other ADC interfaces that are serial such as SPI or I2C would only need isolating two to four pins.

Comment: Why use a 5 cents NE555 to turn the pot's position into a frequency that can be run through one opto and acquired by the FPGA when you can use a $20 ADC ad 12 optos?

Answer (score 4):

Holding CS and RD low permanently will force the ADC to make one single conversion right after power is applied. That value will be presented to the output bus until you remove power. No further conversions will be performed: -

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ok, I see. My next question is do such ADC chips exist that allow for continuous conversion without having to initialise and command the conversion?

Comment: @David777 try looking for a [flash conversion ADC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_ADC)

Comment: Do flash converter ICs for 12 bit exist?

Comment: I don't know. I expect 8 bit ones work but, if you are looking for a real solution to try out look for a converter that can be set to run continuously or toggle the CS and RD lines with an oscillator.